# How to authorize external domain to send to our distribution list in Office365?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

We have a distribution list in our organization called **MAIL-EVERYONE@example.com**.  We use delivery management settings to restrict who can send to this list, and have set up mail contacts for external users that we want to add to this list and that is working fine.

However, this list is growing and changing fairly regularly for users at a specific domain, and it would be much easier if we could set up a method to simply allow all email from that domain to send to our distribution list rather than needing to specify each individual user there.

I haven't found any obvious way to essentially authorize the domain to send to our distribution list, or to somehow allow the external domain to be considered inbound email; I have tried different workarounds with MailUsers, SharedMailboxes, and External Contacts, but haven't found a way for this to work.

One idea that we thought might work is setting up an email address on their end called **MAILTO-EXAMPLE@otherdomain.com** which forwards all mail received to **MAIL-EVERYONE@example.com**, then set that user as a mail contact on our end.  However when users over there send mail to **MAILTO-EXAMPLE@otherdomain.com** the mail is *redirected* and not *forwarded*, as such the *from address* is from the originating user and is subsequently blocked.

I guess the summary of my questions are:

1. Is it possible to authorize an entire external domain permission to send to a distribution group?
2. Is it possible to have Office 365 consider an external domain an internal domain?
3. Is it possible to create a TRUE forward for an email address so that when mail is sent to it it is subsequently forwarded FROM that address?

Comment: What's your problem with allowing anyone to send to the distro group?  Have you considered using something other than a distro group for this address?  It all seems quite convoluted...

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a natural application for moderated transport in Exchange Online (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298007(v=exchg.150).aspx). You could use a combination of example 1 on that page and a transport rule to do what you want, I think.